# How to change GUI box background color for each gui button individual?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The problem is at this part, the color is changing the background also for the PAUSE button and not only for the PLAY/STOP button.

Before i added this part the PAUSE button color changing was working fine but after adding this part in the PLAY/STOP button now the PAUSE part with the colors change is not working good as before. The background colors in the PLAY/STOP button also affecting the PAUSE background color when trying to change the PAUSE button color in runtime in the inspector.

```
if (test == false)
        {
            GUI.backgroundColor = Color.green;
            test1 = "STOP";
        }
        else
        {
            GUI.backgroundColor = Color.red;
            test1 = "PLAY";
        }
```

What i want to do is to be able to manipulate the background color for each button individual so one will not override/affect the other/s.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GUIExamples : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Texture btnTexture;
    public Color color;
    
    public string colorInf;

    private GUIStyle currentStyle = null;
    private Color oldColor;
    private bool test = false;
    private string test1;

    private void Start()
    {
        oldColor = color;
    }

    private void OnGUI()
    {
        if (!btnTexture)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Please assign a texture on the inspector");
            return;
        }

        //GUI.backgroundColor = color;
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 10, 170, 30), "LOOP"))
            Debug.Log("Clicked the button with an image");

        //GUI.backgroundColor = color;
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 50, 170, 30), "CHANGE DIRECTION"))
            Debug.Log("Clicked the button with text");

        //GUI.backgroundColor = color;
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 90, 170, 30), "PING PONG"))
            Debug.Log("Clicked the button with text");

        if (test == false)
        {
            GUI.backgroundColor = Color.green;
            test1 = "STOP";
        }
        else
        {
            GUI.backgroundColor = Color.red;
            test1 = "PLAY";
        }
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 130, 170, 30), test1))
        {
            Debug.Log("Clicked the button with text");
            test = !test;
        }

        InitStyles(); 
        GUI.Box(new Rect(10, 170, 170, 30), "PAUSE", currentStyle);
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 170, 170, 30), "PAUSE", currentStyle))
            Debug.Log("Clicked the button with text");

        
    }

    private void InitStyles()
    {
            currentStyle = null;

            if (oldColor != color)
            {
                currentStyle = null;
            }

            if (currentStyle == null)
            {
                currentStyle = new GUIStyle(GUI.skin.box);
                currentStyle.normal.background = MakeTex(2, 2,
                    new Color(color.r, color.g, color.b));

                oldColor = color;
            }
    }

    private Texture2D MakeTex(int width, int height, Color col)
    {
        Color[] pix = new Color[width * height];
        for (int i = 0; i < pix.Length; ++i)
        {
            pix[i] = col;
        }
        Texture2D result = new Texture2D(width, height);
        result.SetPixels(pix);
        result.Apply();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple GUISkin's.

```
public GUISkin pauseBtnStyle;  
public GUISkin playBtnStyle;
```

and then set the skin before drawing your control.

```
GUI.skin = pauseBtnStyle;  
if (GUI.Button(rect, "Pause")) 
{
    Debug.Log("Pause Clicked");
}  

GUI.skin = playBtnStyle;  
if (GUI.Button(rect, "Play")) 
{
    Debug.Log("Play Clicked");
}
```